# C# saving list of strings to a file saves with blank line between each entry

Tags: c#

Writing a console app in .NET Core 3.1.  In the following, I'm getting all regex matches from a match collection and write them to a text file, each on its own line.  Note that the `modifiedFiles` variable is a list of type `<FileInfo>`.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LogFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string sourcePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourcepath"];
            string targetPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destpath"];
            Regex rx1 = new Regex(@"(Entry\t.*)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


            var modifiedFiles = ModifiedFileFinder.GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours(sourcePath);

                foreach (var file in modifiedFiles)
                {
                var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file.ToString());
                var fileName = file.Name;
                var newFile = String.Concat(targetPath, fileName);
                MatchCollection matches = rx1.Matches(fileContent);

                if (matches.Count > 0)
                    {
                    var result = new List<string>();

                    foreach (Match m in matches)
                    {
                        result.Add(m.Value);
                    }
                    File.WriteAllLines(newFile, result);
                    }
                }  
           }              
       }
   }
```

The text in the resulting file looks like:

```
Entry  this is item 1.
 
Entry  this is item 2.
 
Entry  this is item 3.
```

It has a blank line in between each line of text.  Whereas I need it to look like:

```
Entry  this is item 1.
Entry  this is item 2.
Entry  this is item 3.
```

Comment: It seems that the lines in `result` contains newline character(s).

Comment: The reason for that is likely that `rx1` captures newlines as part of the `.*` at the end. Debugging your applications and looking to see what the values of `m.Value` are would highlight this issue straight away.

Comment: What does the input file look like?  Because calling `File.ReadAllLines` on the input file may help straighten out your problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex captures the whole line, including trailing "\n" (or "\r\n").

Based on the exact file format, you should change your regex to:

```
(Entry\t.*)\n
```

or

```
(Entry\t.*)\r\n
```

then, in foreach loop, use

```
result.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

This adds only the first capturing group, ie what's inside "()", skipping newline characters.

Comment: Or possibly `(Entry\t[^\n]*)` or similar. It really depends on what the text looks like and what they're actually trying to parse out of it.

Comment: `(Entry\t.*)\n` did not work, but `(Entry\t.*)\r\n` did.  Thanks.

Comment: "_Your regex captures the whole line, including trailing "\n" (or "\r\n")._" Not true: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes) shows that `.` does **not** match newline characters (`\n`) so this isn't the reason that you have extra lines in your output file.

> `.` Wildcard: Matches any single character except \n.

It does, however, match carriage return characters (`\r`) which are being included in your output.

Whether the empty lines are visible in your output file entirely depends on the text editing software you are using, and how it interprets a standalone `\r` character.

The most robust way to avoid this is to match all characters except `\n` and `\r`:

`(Entry\t[^\n\r]*)`